# is perlite dust toxic or is it safe for humans to breath

Tags: soil, avocado, hydroponic

I'm growing avocado seeds and I'm wondering as there is 
so many confusing info out there in regards to perlite.

I would like to use it in my pots but I'm not sure if it is toxic or not.

can I keep the plants In my bedroom if there is perlite in the pot?

I know that when its wet it stays in one place. but what about when the pot is dry?

Comment: Have you seen this Q&A which might address your question: https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/49403/is-perlite-safe-to-use-in-the-home-or-will-it-cause-health-issues Also, you've tagged this question with both [tag:soil] and [tag:hydroponic] -- aren't they mutually exclusive?

Comment: hi you can do both at the same time it's a new way of layering it involves no chemical feed at all as the nutrients come from the soil

Comment: Do not put perlite in a blender; is is fine as an undisturbed soil component.

Comment: Likely there is sand ( quartz) in your soil. Risk of silicosis is very low if you do not put it in a blender.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the US National Institutes of Health (not politicized yet, thankfully), perlite dust is NOT hazardous. [Here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4002636/) is a great source for more information - the relevant information is in the Abstract.

That being said, I have some bronchial issues of my own, so I wear a simple dust mask when working with perlite and soilless mix - I just don't like coughing that stuff up for the next 12 hours or so.

Comment: thank you @Jurp the mask is a smart idea.they say it sometimes contains carcinogens so when the pots are in the bedroom/house you need to wear a mask 24-7.

Comment: Perlite doesn't *shed* dust. It is basically a form of porous glass. As the NIH reference says, any dust that was in the perlite you bought is no more hazardous than any form of "nuisance dust", though it can contain a small proportion of silica (i.e. sand) which can be carcinogenic. Don't forget the building panels in your walls and ceiling probably also contain perlite as a lightweight filler material. Wearing a mask 24/7 is paranoia IMO.

Comment: I use a mask only when pouring the perlite into the soilless mix. This is because the airborne perlite particulates (to be very scientific and, I suppose, pedantic) irritate my lungs just like any other form of particulate. For example, I wear the same mask when sweeping my garage, working in the unfinished attic, and working with dry soilless mix (prior to my wetting it). I don't see any reason for wearing a mask after I've combined the perlite and soilless mix.